# CFSE Calculation

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

I have $\ce{[ML6]}$ & $\ce{[MD6]}$ as two complexes. I know the $\Delta_0$ & hybridisation of each of them. How do I calculate the CFSE for $\ce{[ML4D2]}$ ?

**This is my way of thinking :**

I can calculate the CFSE of $\ce{[ML6]}$ & $\ce{[MD6]}$ in terms of Pairing Energy and then do some manipulations to cancel the pairing energy to be left with an equation of the form :

$$a\times(\text{CFSE of }\ce{[ML6]}) + b\times(\text{CFSE of }\ce{[MD6]}) = c$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known. How do I proceed to get the CFSE for $\ce{[ML4D2]}$?

Comment: In the future, please format your posts using [$\LaTeX$](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)